# MySQL: Merge tables with specific conditions

Tags: mysql, database, merge

my problem looks simply but I just can't figure it out. I need to fill secret column with secret data from Table 2, but with several conditions:

- IDs doesn't match
- Color, date and quantity have to match
- Quantity can repeat (with same color and date)
- In that case secret have to match in order by quantity balance (DESC and Table 1 by ID ASC)
- Each row from Table 2 must be used only once (!)
- Some rows from Table 1 doesn't have this pair

Table 1:

```
+----+-------+------------+---------+--------+
| id | color | date       | quantiy | secret |
+----+-------+------------+---------+--------+
|  1 | blue  | 2017-10-29 |       7 |        |
+----+-------+------------+---------+--------+
|  2 | blue  | 2017-10-29 |      13 |        |
+----+-------+------------+---------+--------+
|  3 | blue  | 2017-10-29 |      13 |        |
+----+-------+------------+---------+--------+
|  4 | blue  | 2017-10-30 |       5 |        |
+----+-------+------------+---------+--------+
|  5 | red   | 2017-10-29 |      10 |        |
+----+-------+------------+---------+--------+
|  6 | red   | 2017-10-29 |       8 |        |
+----+-------+------------+---------+--------+
```

Table 2:

```
+----+-------+------------+---------+------------------+--------+
| id | color | date       | quantiy | quantity_balance | secret |
+----+-------+------------+---------+------------------+--------+
| 11 | blue  | 2017-10-29 |       7 |              120 | abc    |
+----+-------+------------+---------+------------------+--------+
| 12 | blue  | 2017-10-29 |      13 |              113 | def    |
+----+-------+------------+---------+------------------+--------+
| 13 | blue  | 2017-10-29 |      13 |              100 | ghi    |
+----+-------+------------+---------+------------------+--------+
| 14 | blue  | 2017-10-30 |       5 |               87 | jkl    |
+----+-------+------------+---------+------------------+--------+
| 15 | red   | 2017-10-29 |      10 |              201 | mno    |
+----+-------+------------+---------+------------------+--------+
| 16 | red   | 2017-10-29 |       8 |              191 | pqr    |
+----+-------+------------+---------+------------------+--------+
```

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Thanks Barmar, but I really tried a lot. Actually I spent several days on this problem because it's very simplified client's DB (not homework) and don't want to bother you with non-solutions. I just could not achieve the uniqueness mentioned in point 5.

Comment: We want you to bother us with non-solutions. We want to show how to correct them, not just do it for you.

Comment: Sorry, I understand what you mean. Somehow I knew that I was far from the right solution. See @Bill Karwin's answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't have a unique way of selecting the row to update, you can't do this with a simple join.

I'm going to answer this with a method that requires windowing functions in MySQL 8.0.

```
WITH
  t1 AS (
    SELECT id, color, date, quantity,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY color, date, quantity ORDER BY id) AS rn
    FROM table1
  ),
  t2 AS (
    SELECT id, color, date, quantity, secret,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY color, date, quantity ORDER BY id) AS rn
    FROM table2
  )
SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE table1 SET secret = ', QUOTE(t2.secret), ' WHERE id = ', t1.id, ';') AS _sql
FROM t2 JOIN t1 USING (color, date, quantity, rn);
```

Output is a series of UPDATE statements:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
| _sql                                           |
+------------------------------------------------+
| UPDATE table1 SET secret = 'abc' WHERE id = 1; |
| UPDATE table1 SET secret = 'def' WHERE id = 2; |
| UPDATE table1 SET secret = 'ghi' WHERE id = 3; |
| UPDATE table1 SET secret = 'jkl' WHERE id = 4; |
| UPDATE table1 SET secret = 'pqr' WHERE id = 6; |
| UPDATE table1 SET secret = 'mno' WHERE id = 5; |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

We can't do the UPDATE directly, because a CTE is not updatable.

Comment: Bill, you are great! :) I just export both tables to PostgreSQL (with windowing functions), run similar query there and voilà... Thanks, you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

possibility you can make views without affecting the original table and you can merge them and can match the columns by the `Quantity` 
Views will be kinda your virtual table exist in your database and you can use that anywhere in the system